# can't seem to match two values in registry

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to get all the NICs on my system and then using that information to insert registry values of `*TCPChecksumOffloadIPv4` etc. However, I am failing this task miserably!

I can get all the GUID's and want to match that to what is in this registry path: `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\*`

I get all the GUID's by this:

```
$GuidSet = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\*" | select -ExpandProperty pschildname
```

Output:

```
{1FE01120-3866-437F-81FF-556B08999AA4}
{2533855F-2A59-485D-87A0-167E5DA39E45}
{2A6471FB-C1D6-47D2-A665-9F276D142D7C}
{306D2DED-18B5-45D8-858E-BB3F49E3BD6A}
{30EF50B2-E4B3-400D-9614-B590E37DE4D8}
{4A208C06-0D99-4DE4-9B2F-86285AEF864E}
{B7883140-E15B-4409-BA1B-96E37A45425C}
{D129DDA8-C64B-46A1-B99A-EA74FC4FAF81}
{D5C9183B-E542-4010-866F-4443AD55F28C}
```

This is where I am stuck now...how can I use this information to match what is in the registry path of `"HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\*"` ?

I tried the below but I get access denied - I think this is because of the "Properties" registry key - **how can I ignore that registry key?**

```
     $path1 = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\*" |?{$_.NetCfgInstanceId -match $guidset} | select -ExpandProperty pspath
```

Once that is done though then do I construct a foreach loop on each entry and then add in the registry keys I need?

**ANSWER:**

you know what...when your in a muddle and you have lots of scripts...take a break, open a new window and start from scrath! That's what I did and in 10min I figured it out...!

```
$aGUID_SET = @(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\*" | select -ExpandProperty pschildname)

Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\*" -exclude "Properties" | 
    Where-Object {$aGUID_SET.Contains($_.NetCfgInstanceId)} | 
        ForEach-Object {
            ""
            $_.DriverDesc
            $_.NetCfgInstanceId
        }
```

Comment: StegMan was correct, to get around that error add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your `Get-ItemProperty` command. Also, don't use `-match` in that command, use `-in`. I say this because `-match` is designed to match strings, and `$guidset` is an array of strings, not a string itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

The `Get-ItemProperty` cmdlet will only get the properties of the items specified, not including any sub-items.

Since the registry values you are looking for are not actually properties of the registry key `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` but instead are properties of subkeys of that key, the first thing we need to do is list the subkeys: `$path = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}"`

We can then use `Get-ChildItem $path` to list the subkeys.

After formatting the paths properly (add Registry:: to the front), you can then input that to `Get-ItemProperty`. I would filter with something like: `Where-Object {$guidset -contains $_.NetcfgInstanceID} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSPath`.

Finally, you should have an array of paths to keys that matched `$guidset`, which
`Set-ItemProperty` can take.

EDIT: The error you are receiving is because permissions on those "Properties" subkeys is restricted. I would tack an `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `Get-ChildItem` because it is not a terminating error and does not actually affect the results.

Comment: thanks for that - I put the answer in my question and what did I do...took a break, started from scratch on a new page and in 10min I figured it out....having too much code on one script really confuses you..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
ForEach ($item in $(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\*" |?{$_.NetCfgInstanceId -match $guidset} | select -ExpandProperty pspath)) {

    Try {
       Write-Host $item
    } Catch {
       Write-Host "error..."
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting "Requested registry access is not allowed." - I am pretty sure it is becuase of a key that is called "Properties" (for some reason it is really secure)...any idea how I can do all the keys except that Properties key?